# kafka Connect: Tasks.max more than # of partitions but the status says RUNNING

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In our setup, we have 50 tasks and 40 partitions in the topic. We have 2 workers. Ideally, the connector should start just 40 tasks but we see all 50 tasks have the status as RUNNING. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

There are may be idle tasks, but that does not necessarily mean they are in `UNASSIGNED` or `FAILURE` state. They are active and running as part of a consumer group (assuming a sink connector).

If you had a source connector, then there are just 50 running producer threads, sending data to all 40 partitions. There isn't a 1:1 limitation on how many producers like there are for consumers.

You're welcome to `PUT` a new configuration for the connector and set `tasks.max` back to 40.

Comment: What does a task in a connector do if it has no partitions assigned?